# Difference between scipy linprog with mixed integrality constraints and milp?

Tags: python, scipy, linear-programming, mixed-integer-programming

I'd like to know the difference between those 2 functions of Scipy:

- [linprog](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linprog.html) when it is used with mixed integrality constraints - i.e. some variables should be integers and others should be continuous
- [milp](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.milp.html)

I do see that they have a different syntax but they seem both based on the HiGHS solver, so is there a fundamental difference in the solving algorithm? Can we expect the same computation time using one function or the other?

**EDIT**: I found a good explanation of the differences in the Scipy Github repo https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/18700

Comment: With the proper selection of options they may be identical and call the same functions under the hood. If that's the case, the separation is just convenience (you don't have to toggle as many options when you use `milp` as you would need to do if you wanted to run `linprog` for the same problem.

Comment: Thanks. Could you give an example of option that may be different in ```milp``` and ```linprog``` in their default behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation:

[`milp`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.milp.html)

[`linprog`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linprog.html)

In terms of signatures,

- `linprog` accepts one bare matrix for, respectively, `A_eq` and `A_ub` constraints. `milp` accepts `LinearConstraint` objects which can do the same thing but are more generic, having separate lower and upper bounds and being able to specify multiple separate constraints in a sequence. (`milp` can also accept bare arrays so long as those are directly constructor-unpack convertible to `LinearConstraint`).
- Similarly, `linprog` accepts bare matrices for `bounds`, and `milp` accepts a `Bounds` convenience object.
- `linprog` accepts different `options` dictionary keys than `milp`. For instance, with `linprog` you can set `maxiter` and with `milp` you cannot.
- `milp` only wraps `HiGHS`. `linprog` accepts a `method` that should usually be set to `highs`, but has other legacy methods, including simplex and interior point. These legacy methods should usually not be used:

> **Deprecated since version 1.9.0:** *method=’simplex’* will be removed in SciPy 1.11.0. It is replaced by *method=’highs’* because the latter is faster and more robust.

For exotic (and deprecated) use cases, `linprog` supports callbacks and `milp` does not. The documentation about this is not explicit in `linprog`, but for the non-deprecated methods (`highs` and family), `callback` is ignored.

Due to the constraint convenience wrappers, you should usually be using `milp` unless you have a very good reason.

> Can we expect the same computation time using one function or the other?

Yes. The only (marginal) time difference you might or might not be able to detect is in problem setup and conversion time; basically all of the code prior to `HiGHS`.